# Using OpenJDK 12 in Jenkins (Docker version)

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I tried to install OpenJDK 12 in jenkins, with *.tar.gz installer but i get the error `Cannot run program "/bin/java"`

JAVA_HOME=/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/java12

**Note** I created the directory "hudson.model.JDK" myself.

here is the tool configuration
[image]

full error log
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JDK 12` has one bug logged
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6746185
according to this `Malformed URL` is invalid, So jenkins is not able to download JDK

Simple solution is download `JDk` from this link, or whatever you like and add Open JDK in jenkins as I do

https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk12.0.1/69cfe15208a647278a19ef0990eea691/12/GPL/openjdk-12.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz

Download JDK and extract it to one folder.

Manage Jenkins> Global Configurations> Add JDK>  
1. Name: Open JDK(Or whatever you want)
2. JAVA_HOME: \Open_JDK\

like in my case
`E:\Open_JDK\openjdk-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin\jdk-11.0.2`

[image]

in jenkins

[image]

Save and exit, everything working fine

Happy Jenkins, Happy to help

Comment: Thanks for explanation but still is not working and I get `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/var/jenkins_home/tools/jdk-12.0.1/bin/java" (in directory "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/coorperate-pom"): error=2, No such file or directory`

Comment: try OpenJDK 11, Might be some compatibility issues with JDK12

Comment: I tried exactly the same version as you 11.0.2, but still NOT FOUND

Answer (score 3):

[JDK Tool Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JDK+Tool+Plugin) in Jenkins only support the automatic download of version up to Java SDK 1.9 so I will write the process made by me in order to config OpenJDK-11(I'm using this specific version but another version can be used) in a Jenkins running in a Docker container:

1. Login into the host server where the docker container is running using SSH 
   service.
2. Check the running containers with the command: `docker ps`
3. Get in into the Jenkins container with the command(in my case, the container name is "jenkins"): `docker exec -it containerName /bin/bash`
4. Download the OpenJDK 11: `cd /usr/local && wget https://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk11/ri/openjdk-11+28_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz`
5. Unpack the downloaded file: `tar -zxvf openjdk-11+28_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz`
6. Now you will have a folder "jdk-11" under `/usr/local`.
7. Go to Global Tools Configuration in Jenkins and set up the SDK config like the showed image:

[image]

8. Now you can make use of a different version of Java SDK in Jenkins builds using as label "Java SE 11".

Answer (score 0):

JDK 12 is not yet supported by Jenkins.
Link: https://jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/java/